# Cannot access the SD card after formating on camera

Tags: formatting, sd-card, camera

I have a 64GB SD card and a Pentax K7 camera. At some point my camera stopped reading the card, and I formatted in camera's settings. Now, I can take pictures and read them on my camera, but my PC does not see it. Disk manager shows it as Disk 1 without any letters assigned.
I tried:

- all of the Disk Manager's possible actions, but it always says 'The system cannot find the file specified'
- SD Card Formatter that just wouldn't see it.

I don't care about the files, and as I understood from [this article](https://superuser.com/questions/564170/why-is-my-sd-card-only-readable-in-the-camera-but-not-in-the-computer). I just want to know if I can format it again for it to be accessible on pc, and if so, how?

Comment: The only 2 things available to me there were 'Format' and 'Change Drive letter and paths'. For both of those it would just say  'The system cannot find the file specified'.

Comment: I think by the file it means the card itself, as there is just one button 'ok' that does not lead to any action.  So, it does not allow me to format it.

Comment: It's likely the card has failed. Otherwise it wouldn't have stopped working in the first place. // Can you try using a different SD card reader?

Comment: @DanielB I had the same when I formatted my SD card on my phone. Exact behavior. Windows would say the card was damaged, but worked fine on my phone. I managed to format the card after removing partitions and recreating it and windows was happy with the card again.

Answer (score 1):

When a camera or mobile phone formats an SD card, it uses their own partition layout. Windows can't deal with the format, which is why the disk appears empty or corrupted.

In order to use the SD card in windows again, you have to reinitalize the disk from within Windows.

You should be able to right-click the partition and remove it.
Then create a new partition as FAT32 or NTFS and format it. Note that a FAT32 can only be formatted up to 32 gig on windows, but can be formatted to more using a tool. After the partition is created SD Card formatter can probably format it correctly for you.

Alternatively, place the card in your camera, and connect the camera using USB and access the card that way.

Comment: It says 'The volume was created successfully but it was not formatted. Retry the format using the format task' and then also 'The volume was created successfully but it was not assigned an access path. Retry assigning the access path by using the change drive letters and paths task.' When I try to do so, it shows me the same 'The system cannot find the file specified'. Also, the file system in the partition is shown as RAW.

Comment: Cameras wouldn't do that. They use FAT32 or possibly exFAT. Mobile phones are something else entirely.

Comment: Before I've done all these actions to card it would be shown as exFAT.

Comment: @DanielB it can be vFat which Windows cannot recognize.

Comment: Oleg, try formatting now from the context menu. You will be limited to 32 gig, but that should at least get you started and possibly format using the SD Card formatter

Comment: Summarizing what @LPChip stated, 1. Using a drive tool, such as diskmgmt.msc or DiskGenius, *remove all partitions, leaving all space unused.* Commit the action. 2. Create a single partition. 3. Format the partition. exFAT or FAT32 (https://www.howtogeek.com/316977/how-to-format-usb-drives-larger-than-32gb-with-fat32-on-windows/). Again, commit all actions.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by first using Command prompt as it was described here [here](https://www.diskpart.com/articles/how-to-fix-raw-hard-drive-to-ntfs-3889.html#1) until the
 `format fs=ntfs label=new quick` step.

So,

```
 diskpart
list disk
select disk 1
attributes disk clear readonly
clean
create partition primary
```

Then, took the card out, put it in, and formatted in the disk management.

It wasn't letting me to format it directly in the command prompt for some reason, and without re-ejecting I also couldn't do anything with it in the disk manager.

Comment: The question is: is it card recognized by camera?

Comment: I don't have the camera anymore, but I would assume no. I think it uses some old volume formats, and when I had it it would not accept any new cards I had without formatting them. So, as the card is now switched back to a modern format, I think it would ask for formatting again.